# How to read variable from one php file to another for Plotly.newPlot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plotly

I am new to Plotly.newPlot. My data is like this in test.php:

```
<?php 
  $testx1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
  $testy1 = "11,22,33,44,55,66,77";
  $testx2 = "5,6,7,8,9,10";
  $testy2 = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70";  
?>
```

You can see my Plotly.newPlot in view.php:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [<?php echo $testx1 ;?>],
  y: [<?php echo $testy2 ;?>],
  fill: 'none',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'Mean'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [<?php echo $testx2 ;?>],
  y: [<?php echo $testy2 ;?>],
  fill: 'none',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: '5 percentile'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  title: '',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'GA (weeks)',
    titlefont: {
      family: '"Roboto", sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      size: 14,
      color: '#7f7f7f'
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'BPD mm',
    titlefont: {
      family: '"Roboto", sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      size: 14,
      color: '#7f7f7f'
    }
  }
};

var config = {
  modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud'],
  displaylogo: false
};

var config1 = {
  displayModeBar: false
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv', data, layout, config1);
  Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv1', data, layout, config1);
  Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv2', data, layout, config1);
});
```

My problem is that I have hard coding those variables from test.php. If any new variable is added in test.php I could not read those variables in chart because I did not assign that variable in view.php.

Also, if I delete any variable in test.php, it gives 'error undefined variable' because that variable is assigned in view.php but not in test.php.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use an array of arrays for the data. Then use `JSON_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` to output all data at once into a single JS var. Then use that var (again an array of arrays) to setup your graphs.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG thanks for your response ,i did not get you ,could you please explain .it is very help to me .Thanks

Comment: Like this: https://ideone.com/OEgPG7

Comment: Hi @ChrisG thanks your correct ,but in my case I am putting those variable in test.php dynamically by UI using CMS ,so in that test.php has variables only i can write  .if I write $data it go off when I trying to insert new  variable.

Comment: Is there any way to read  variable  from test.php file into view.php file ?

Comment: `read variable from test.php file into view.php file` what do you mean? The ultimate goal is to create graphs based on CMS input, correct? You could use a CSV file instead, or JSON, or database rows. If I understand correctly, this is about a) storing a bunch of x/y-coordinate pairs and b) displaying them as graphs. Like you said you've hardcoded the data, which will not work with dynamic data. So you need to find a dynamic solution. I have no idea how the user inputs the data into the CMS, but storing the input in a CSV file or database is trivial.

Comment: @ChrisG The ultimate goal is to create graphs based on CMS input, correct? Yas ,what ever you said exactly correct .Thanks

Comment: Ok, so your question title is wrong. You are asking the wrong question. How is the CMS accepting input? Via a `<form>`? You need to edit your question so it is about your *actual* problem.

Comment: sorry not CMS from the UI .i have two input forms(X andY) those i extended by using clone() with diff. id each input ,based on those i am giving input values ,those values stored into test.php .so when ever I reload the chart page(view.php) it read those variables from test.php, like this i have done .Thanks

Comment: Again: you need a dynamic approach. If you use multiple `<input name="x[]">` then `$_POST['x']` will be an array.

Comment: Yas,i am using codeigniter framework this <input name="x[]"> values sending into controller by using ajax call from that controller I am opening test.php file (by using fopen()) and writing those vairables like this fwrite($fp, "$".$xy_id[$j]." = \"".$xy_val[$j]."\";\n");

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong ,how can i design data in test.php for proper reading.Thanks

Comment: That is just wrong, sorry. Don't do that. That is the worst possible way. The controller should pass the data directly to the view, or write it to a database. Manually composing PHP source code with hardcoded variables is just wrong.